# Issue with Python Code for Emission Abatement Calculation

Tags: python, sympy

I'm facing an issue with the Python code to calculate emission abatement (EA) for two industries (MACA and MACB). The code is not giving the expected results for EA and MACA.

Here's the code:

```py
import sympy as sp

EA, EB = sp.symbols('EA EB')
abatement_percentage = 40

MACA = 450 - 3 * EA
MACB = 300 - 2 * EB

EA_value = sp.solve(sp.Eq(MACA, 0), EA)[0]
EB_value = sp.solve(sp.Eq(MACB, 0), EB)[0]

EA_abatement = EA_value * (abatement_percentage / 100)
EB_abatement = EB_value * (abatement_percentage / 100)

total_abatement = EA_abatement + EB_abatement

EB_value = sp.solve(sp.Eq(MACA, MACB), EB)[0]
EA_value = total_abatement - EB_value

MACA_value = MACA.subs(EB, EB_value)

print("EA =", EA_value)
print("EB =", EB_value)
print("EA after abatement:", EA_abatement)
print("EB after abatement:", EB_abatement)
print("Total abatement:", total_abatement)
print("MACA =", MACA_value)
```

Expected Output:

```
EA = 78
EB = 42
EA after abatement: 31.2
EB after abatement: 16.8
Total abatement: 48.0
MACA = 216
```

**Mathematical steps taken:**

1. Given: MACA = 450 - 3EA and MACB = 300 - 2EB
2. To find when MACA = 0 and MACB = 0:

   - 450 - 3EA = 0, solving for EA gives EA = 150
   - 300 - 2EB = 0, solving for EB gives EB = 150
3. Abatement of 40%:

   - EA = 150 * 40% = 60
   - EB = 150 * 40% = 60
4. EA + EB = 60 + 60 = 120
5. EA = 120 - EB
6. Finding the value of EB when MACA = MACB:

   - 450 - 3EA = 300 - 2EB
   - Substituting EA = 120 - EB in the above equation, we get: 450 - 3(120 - EB) = 300 - 2EB
   - Simplifying the equation, we find 5EB = 210, which gives EB = 42
   - EA = 120 - 42 = 78
7. Now, MACA = 450 - 3EA = 450 - 3(78) = 216

**Issue:**
The computed values for MACA and EA are incorrect, and the code doesn't provide the expected results. The computed value of MACA should be 216, whereas the current code produces an incorrect value. The computed value of EA should also be 78, but the current code generates a different value.

Please help in fixing the code to obtain the correct results for the emission abatement calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your expected values above your written-out steps don't match, so I will be going with the values from the written-out steps.

The reason the code results don't match up with your hand calculations is because you didn't tell your code to perform the same calculations. For example, in step 5 your hand calculations show that you define the symbol `EA` to be `120 - EB`, yet in your code you replace `EA_value` (computed earlier) with 120 minus the pre-abatement *value* of EB, `EB_value`.

Written below is code that replicates your mathematical steps (the steps are commented) and gets the exact same results.

```py
import sympy as sp

EA, EB = sp.symbols("EA EB")
abatement_percentage = 40

# step 1
MACA = 450 - 3 * EA
MACB = 300 - 2 * EB

# step 2
EA_before_abatement = sp.solve(sp.Eq(MACA, 0), EA)[0]
EB_before_abatement = sp.solve(sp.Eq(MACB, 0), EB)[0]
print(EA_before_abatement, EB_before_abatement) # 150 150

# step 3
EA_after_abatement = EA_before_abatement*(abatement_percentage / 100)
EB_after_abatement = EB_before_abatement*(abatement_percentage / 100)
print(EA_after_abatement, EB_after_abatement) # 60 60

# step 4
total_abatement_value = EA_after_abatement + EB_after_abatement
print(total_abatement_value) # 120

# step 5
EA_from_abatement = total_abatement_value - EB
print(EA_from_abatement) # 120 - EB

# step 6 bullet 1
combined_eq = sp.Eq(MACA, MACB)
print(combined_eq) # 450 - 3EA = 300 - 2EB

# step 6 bullet 2
combined_eq_subbed = combined_eq.subs(EA, EA_from_abatement)
print(combined_eq_subbed) # 3EB + 90 = 300 - 2EB

# step 6 bullet 3
EB_final = sp.solve(combined_eq_subbed, EB)[0]
print(EB_final) # 42

# step 6 bullet 4
EA_final = EA_from_abatement.subs(EB, EB_final)
print(EA_final) # 78

# step 7
MACA_value = MACA.subs(EA, EA_final)
print(MACA_value) # 216
```